# How to use Javascript to get elements in window created on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page with that creates a dropdown window on-the-fly when a link is clicked, as shown in the following (edited) javascript function:

```
tbiObj._login = function (objEle) {
    var windowName = 'TBIOBJ_LOGIN';
    var tabObjLoginWindow = tbiObj.getWindow(windowName);

    //if tabObjLoginWindow doesn't exist then create it here (code excised)

    var windowDiv = tabObjLoginWindow.getWindowId('body');
    var windowHTML = $('LOGINDIALOG').innerHTML;
    $(windowDiv).innerHTML = windowHTML;
    tabObjLoginWindow.show('dropdown', objEle);
}
```

The template (LOGINDIALOG) that supplies the "innerHTML" is defined later in the page as follows, using display:none:

```
<div id="LOGINDIALOG" style="display:none;">
    <div id="LOGIN.ERRORS" style="display:none; color:red;"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="GrBlue" style="white-space:nowrap;">User Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input class="GrBlueEdit" type="text" id="LOGIN.UNAME" / style="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="GrBlue" style="white-space:nowrap;">Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input autocomplete="off" class="GrBlueE" type="password" id="LOGIN.PWORD" / style="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have the need to change some of the attributes and add a handler to the elements in the dropdown window. I have been experimenting (I'm not an experienced js or jquery coder) and have tried to get to the template elements to change them BEFORE the window is created and the HTML copied. I have been able to change only the "type" attribute of LOGIN.UNAME and LOGIN.PWORD but not others (e.g. style, class) nor can I add event handlers like onkeydown nor can I change the value. My thought was that I might need to "get to" these elements AFTER they've been loaded into the body of the window, but I don't know how. I can display the variable windowHTML defined in the function but that's it. So my questions are:

**1.** Why is it not possible, via js or jQuery (or if it is then where am I failing) to change the value, style, class, etc. of the elements LOGIN.UNAME and LOGIN.PWORD, and why is it not possible to add event handlers (e.g. onkeydown)?

**2.** How can I access the DOM of the window contents after it has been created?

Now, chances are, I might even be making mistakes in asking these questions, but I'd like to work through this. Any pointers to resources or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a complete sample on jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: Elements added to the DOM after page load can't be directly accessed. As such, access to/event for these nodes need to be delegated by an element (usually its parent) that already existed at page load. More here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/delegate/